# Why would last_insert_id() be returning a value on a failed insert?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter-2

Using codeigniter and a table with a unique key constraint as follows:

```
UNIQUE KEY `user_identity_unique` (`site_id`,`user_id`,`event_id`)
```

Then inserting data into that table with the following method:

```
$this->db->insert( 'events', $data );
return $this->db->insert_id();
```

When the insert fails due to a key constraint, `$this->db->insert_id()` is still returning a value even though nothing was inserted. I'm positive mySQL is returning an error because of the result of calling `$this->db->_error_message()` ...

```
Duplicate entry '267-83880-07' for key 'user_identity_unique'
```

This seems like incorrect behavior -- can anyone familiar with this shed some light? Why would last_insert_id still be returning a value? (in this case, the id of a totally unrelated row)

Comment: Did you read the documentation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It returns the id of the last successfull insert made through this connection.

Comment: For some reason I'd always though it was the ID of the last insert attempt and 0 if it failed -- ugh. Thank you.